# Why does ASP.Net locks when I update code with TortoiseSVN

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn

when I update Adobe Flash/Flex code that is not related to ASP.Net with TortoiseSVN (latest) on a Windows Server 2008, the complete website locks and stop responding.

Is it ASP.Net recompiling my code, is it IIS 7 or is it Tortoise locking the file system?

How can I prevent or minimize this if I need to do an update when 1000 users are using the ASP.Net website?

UPDATE:
Thanks to Aito and Bryan, I learned more about AppDomain. I found these two links where I discover that folder creation/deletion recycle the AppDomain in ASP.Net 2.

-->If TortoiseSVN creates folders in it's hidden .svn folders hierarchy, I guess it will lock the app!

ASP.NET v2.0 - AppDomain recycles, more common than before
[http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-*2D00*-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-_2D00_-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx)

FIX: ASP.NET 2.0-connected applications on a Web site may appear to stop responding
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272

I'm testing this.

Carl

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to separate your repository directory from the directory that IIS use. You can pass the files with a deploy script. 
Your problem perhaps is that the files that you updated are in use, and the conflicts come.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I suspect this is not completely true, see this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-_2D00_-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Aito is correct... You are causing an appdomain reset by updating files in the application directory.  Use svn export to update to your actual working dir.  But just like any deployment, you need to figure out a strategy for handling this on a live site.